# Add feature event

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I do not know how can I create `add` event, or attach a listener to an event when a feature is added to the source. At this moment I have a bunch of other events, like:

```
draw.on("drawend", function (e) {
//....
});
```

I thought that `drawend` event is what I need, but as it turned out, when this event happens, the feature is not yet added to the source.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use 'addfeature' event:

```
source.on( 'addfeature', function (ft) {
    // ft - feature being added
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding it manually to the source:
you add the draw interaction to an overlay

```
 var features = new ol.Collection();
 var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: new ol.source.Vector({features: features}),
     style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 2
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
            })
        })
    })
 });
 featureOverlay.setMap(map);

 var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: features, // we set the newly drawn feature on the overlay declared previously
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('Polygon') // for example polygon
    });
```

in the drawend event you push the feature to the source layer you want

```
draw.on('drawend', function(event) {
     yourSource.addFeature(event.feature);
}
```